# Target a checkbox in *ngfor checkbox list

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes that are binded to an object in my component typescript file, I want it to check/uncheck on the list when user clicks on the checkbox, but for some reason, it only checks the and uncheck the first checkbox on the list and not the one that user has clicked on.
Here is the code below:

```
<div>
  <ul class="reports-container">
    <li *ngFor="let item of data.reports" [class.active]="selectedReport==item" >
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{'savedreport'+i}}" class="k-checkbox" [checked]="item.IsSubscribed" [value]="item.IsSubscribed"(change)="onChkBoxChange($event,item)" />
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

here is the typescript function:

```
onChkBoxChange(event, item: SavedReport) {
   item.IsSubscribed = event.target.checked;
}
```

when I put a breakpoint it always passes in the first item from the list, any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry about the previous answer, I had misunderstood. You simply want the value of the checkbox be properly bound to item.IsSubscribed, right? Why don't you use two-way binding? `[(value)] = "item.IsSubscribed"`

Comment: No worries, that was a very good point not sure how that didn't come to my mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael Beeson suggested I used two-way binding on my checkbox value, that solved the problem, so the code is now:

```
<div>
  <ul class="reports-container">
    <li *ngFor="let item of data.reports" [class.active]="selectedReport==item" >
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{'savedreport'+i}}" class="k-checkbox" [checked]="item.IsSubscribed" [(value)]="item.IsSubscribed"(change)="onChkBoxChange($event,item)" />
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Advice:** use angular forms for this that's why forms exist in angular is
 gonna simplify the whole case like yours.

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checboxlist?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to show you how to occur this by using reactive forms and `FormArray` in angular you even can use template driven forms if you want to, the point is using `forms` feature in angular gonna save your time and effort when you encounter such a case.

**html**

```
<div>
  <ul class="reports-container">
    <form [formGroup]="checkboxForm">
      <div formArrayName="checkboxList" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="{{'savedreport'+i}}" [name]="item" [formControlName]="i" class="k-checkbox" (change)="onChkBoxChange($event, i)" />
          {{item}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: [ '...' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  data: string[] = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'];
  checkboxForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkboxForm = new FormGroup({
      checkboxList: new FormArray([])
    });
    this.arrayOfCheckboxs();
  }

  private arrayOfCheckboxs() {
    const formArr = this.checkboxForm.get('checkboxList') as FormArray;
    this.data.forEach(item => {
      formArr.push(new FormControl());
    });
  }

  onChkBoxChange(e: MouseEvent, idx: number) {
    console.log(`${(<HTMLInputElement>e.target).name}: ${this.checkboxForm.get('checkboxList').value[idx]}`);
  }
}
```